# Generate a summarizing word based on a set of words

Tags: pyspark, nlp, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I'm very new to NLP, so I have some theoretical question.
Let's say I have the following Spark dataframe:

```
+--+------------------------------------------+
|id|                                 word_list|
+--+------------------------------------------+
| 1| apple, banana, lime, juice, cherry, peach|
| 2| sauce, cabbage, cucumber, tomatoes, pesto|
| 3|  cocoa, coffee, bottle, tea, water, juice|
+--+------------------------------------------+
```

I need for each `id` to extract a generic word that describes the predominant set of semantically similar words in the `word_list` column. Desired output:

```
+--+------------------------------------------+----------+
|id|                                 word_list|  category|
+--+------------------------------------------+----------+
| 1| apple, banana, lime, juice, cherry, peach|     fruit|
| 2| sauce, cabbage, cucumber, tomatoes, pesto|vegetables|
| 3|  cocoa, coffee, bottle, tea, water, juice| beverages|
+--+------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Is there any unsupervised NLP algorithm that can be used to get the desired output?

Comment: This is more a design question so it would be better to ask on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. There's no standard algorithm which does this, however it can be done based on some semantic similarity. Based on the example, [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) would be a good candidate. Similarity with pretrained word embeddings could also work.